# Ubuntu desktop not working after adjusting effects on compiz config manager

Tags: compiz

I unable to disable the desktop or anything, but when I reboot, all I can see is the mouse and a dialog appear saying that compiz has crashed. The terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) doesn't work, and neither control alternative delete to log out works. What can I do to restore everything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

1. Press **Control** + **Alt** + **F1** and log in.
2. In terminal run **unity --reset**.

Comment: But not everyone is using Unity.  I don't, but I still use Compiz.  But if not running Unity, using a virtual terminal, as you suggested, and renaming or deleting the Compiz configuration in the home directory might be another option.